# Automatically turn on grayscale mode in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, grayscale

I want grayscale mode to turn on at a specific time every day, then turn off automatically a few hours later. I know <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> can be used to do it manually but it would be great to automate the process such as turning on at 9pm and off at 7am for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. You need a tool for sending the keys
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
and a way to schedule this sending. These tools are:

- [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
- The [SCHTASKS batch command](https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html),
  or alternatively the Task Scheduler.

You will need to create a AutoHotkey script to send the key combination,
which is a one-liner file with the `.ahk` extension:

```
send, #^c
```

You will need to schedule its execution at the days and times that you wish,
using the SCHTASKS command or the Task Scheduler.

You may also disable the hotkey
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
by changing in the registry the DWORD item `HotkeyEnabled` at the key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ColorFiltering`.
Its value is `0` to disable and `1` to enable, and the modification takes
effect immediately.
You may do so programmatically by either using again AutoHotkey with the
[RegWrite command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegWrite.htm),
or by using the batch
[REG command](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html).

Comment: This seems to work to turn on and off grayscale, but is there a way the script can be activated only if it was activated the night before? For example, if the computer was shutdown at 11pm and the script did not activate, then grayscale mode should not activate in the morning (since instead of turning grayscale off it would turn it on if not activated the night before).

Comment: Also, it seems I am getting the error "Script file not found: C:\\Users\Username" when running the script via task scheduler.

Comment: You can modify the script's behavior by various means, for example using the existence of some file as a switch to tell the script to do its work (or not). An error in the task scheduler means bad task definition.

Comment: You can use the registry values to check if grayscale is active or not. For example, the following script always turns grayscaling off but never on (for the converse replace the if check by `if (not isActive)`). ```#NoEnv 
#Warn
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

RegRead, isActive, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ColorFiltering, Active

if (isActive)
 send, #^c
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Windows 10 doesn't officially support automatic grayscaling depending on the time yet. You can try suggesting that to Windows through the Windows' Feedback Hub.